# django date filter time past

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a nice filter I can use in Django template to allow me to turn a datetime into time period ago from now.

e.g.

```
{{ mydate | date_ago }}
```

that would display things like

```
12 seconds ago
2 hours ago
yesterday 
4 days ago
2 weeks ago
12 jan 2001
```

where by after some distance it just displays the normal date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`timesince`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)